# How to use other languages in an HTML file?

Tags: html

I know how to use Javascript in an HTML file, via the `<script>` and `</script>` elements. But is there a way to do this with languages besides Javascript, like Python, C++, or Java?

P.S. I have seen something like `<script src="text/python">`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: But usually with server side languages, you just save the file with a certain extension and then use their syntax in the file and it will work (if your server is set up to serve those types of files) - here's an example of python: https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-and-viewing-html-files-with-python

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer -- you cannot, since to execute Python code you need Python interpreter, which is not a case for an arbitrary Client/Browser. Although you still can do something with [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly), [Chrome Native Client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client), etc. Thus, it is possible to run, e.g. C/C++ code on the web-page, however it has some limitations:

> The purpose of Wasm is to enable the JavaScript engine of a web browser to execute page scripts nearly as fast as native machine code. But this is not a full replacement for JavaScript; rather, Wasm is only intended for performance-critical portions of page scripts. Wasm code runs in the same sandbox as regular script code, but only regular scripts have direct access to the DOM tree.